# C++ class template

Tags: c++, templates

i am trying to get these class template in C++ to work. But there is always this error.
there is some kind of error in overloading but i don't know what.
i have tried overloading << operator using member function but there is still error.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int MAX = 10;
template <class T>
class mstack
{
    T stk[MAX];
    int top;

public:
    mstack()
    {
        top = -1;
    }

    void push(T data)
    {
        if(top==MAX-1)
        {
            cout << endl << "stack is full" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            top++;
            stk[top] = data;
        }
    }

    T pop()
    {
        if (top==-1)
        {
            cout << endl << "stack is empty" << endl;
            return NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            T data = stk[top];
            top--;
            return data;
        }
    }
};

class mcomplex
{
    float img, real;

public:
    mcomplex()
    {
        real = 0;
        img = 0;
    }

    mcomplex(float r, float i)
    {
        real = r;
        img = i;
    }

    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream &o,mcomplex &c);
};

ostream& operator<< (ostream &o, mcomplex &c)
{
    o << c.real << "\t" << c.img;
    return o;
}

int main()
{
    mcomplex c1(1.5f,2.5f), c2(3.5f,4.5f), c3(-1.5f,-0.6f);
    mstack <mcomplex> s3;
    s3.push(c1);
    s3.push(c2);
    s3.push(c3);
    cout << endl << (s3.pop());
    cout << endl << s3.pop();
    cout << endl << s3.pop() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

compiler error is as following:

> |76|error: no match for 'operator<<'  (operand types are
>   'std::basic_ostream::__ostream_type {aka 
>   std::basic_ostream}' and 'mcomplex')
>
> |62|note: candidate: std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&,
>   mcomplex&)
>
> |77|error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type
>   'mcomplex&'  from an rvalue of type 'mcomplex'
>
> |78|error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 
>   'std::basic_ostream::__ostream_type {aka
>   std::basic_ostream}' and  'mcomplex')

can anyone show what is the error here?

Comment: You cannot pass a temporary value to a function that takes a non-const reference as a parameter. Your overloads must take a `const` reference as a parameter.

Comment: Have you tried writing a non-template version?

Answer (score 1):

Your pop() function is returning a temporary value. Taking non-const reference to this value doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Although it depends on your purpose, you should throw something exception like as follows, not T():

```
if (top==-1)
{
    throw std::runtime_error("stack is empty");
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6e896cc7bcb12db6)

Comment: yeah thats way better. i am currently learning c++ and do not know about exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Got this thing to finally work.
corrections were.

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream &o,const mcomplex &c)
{
    o << c.real << "\t" << c.img;
    return o;
}
```

and

```
if (top==-1)
    {
        cout << endl << "stack is empty" << endl;
        return T();
    }
```